# How to Freeze position x of a prefab instantiate via Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i tried to make my blocks prefab stop moving when it touched the player, i can stop the spawn of the block, but i want to stop the already spawned block so it can look better, but whenever i tried this, the one that get freeze is the one inside my prefab folder, not in the hierarchy

i have tried to disable the script altogether, freeze the x position

this is my block movement script

```
public class Block_Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Rigidbody rb;
    public int speed;


    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void stopMovement()
    {
        print("Stopped");
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition;
    }
}
```

and this is my collision script

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision block)
    {
        if (block.gameObject.tag.Equals("Blocks") == true)
        {
            Timer_Script.stopTimer();
            Block_Spawner.gameOver = true;
            Block_Movement.stopMovement();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `static` for this at all

Isn't the block basically the thing you collide with?

=>

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent<Block_Movement>(out var blockMovement))
    {
        Timer_Script.stopTimer();
        Block_Spawner.gameOver = true;
        blockMovement.stopMovement();
    }
}
```

and accordingly

```
public class Block_Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerilizeField] private Rigidbody rb;
    public int speed;


    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }

    public void stopMovement()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition;

        // also disable this component so the FixedUpdate isn't called anymore
        enabled = false;
        // could even consider to remove the Rigidbody component all along
        //Destroy(rb);
    }
}
```

---

Or was your question how to rather stop **ALL** blocks, not only the one you collide with?

In that case you can stick with the `static` but should keep track of all block instances:

```
public class Block_Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;
    public int speed;

    private static readonly HashSet<Block_Movement> instances = new ();

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
  
        instances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        instances.Remove(this);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void stopMovement()
    {
        print("Stopped");
        foreach(var instance in instances)
        {
            instance.rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition;
            instance.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks, even though i'm still not 100% sure how this works, but i'll learn it